# If the difference between two consecutive elements tends to 0, then the sequence converges? Mistake in proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I tried proving that if $a_{n+1}$ - $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ $0$, then $a_n$ converges. 
Now I searched for this example here and saw many counterexamples, yet I don't understand where my proof went wrong.

**Proof:**

Proof by induction that $a_n$ is Cauchy. 
base: 
 for $k=1$ we know that $|a_{n+k} - a_n|< \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$ > $0$.

Step: 
 assume this condition is true for $k$ and prove for $k+1$, then:
$$|a_{n+k+1}-a_n| = |a_{n+k+1}-a_k+a_k+a_n| \leq |a_{n+k+1}-a_k| + |a_k-a_n| \leq 2\epsilon$$
So by this point can't I say than $a_n$ converges from Cauchy?

The only thing I could think about was that maybe the induction doesn't cover the Cauchy condition that says this needs to be $\forall m,n \geq N$ but I never encountered this so I can't really trust my reasoning.

Comment: The statement is false. Take $a_n=n+\frac 1 n$.

Comment: "For $k=1$, we know that $\lvert a_{n+k}-a_n\rvert<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$": no, you **don't** know that $a_n=a_{n+1}$ (whatever $n$ you might be considering).

Comment: "For $k=1$ we know that $|a_{n+k}-a_n|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$" <-- That hardly makes much sense. How do you know that? And for which values of $n$ are you claiming this? For all $n$? For some $n$?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to write for n bigger than some N, I didn’t think it was true for every n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base condition is not a correct statement of what it means for $\ a_{n+1}-a_n\ $ to converge to zero.  A correct statement is:

> For any $\ \epsilon>0\ $ there is a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that $\ \big|\,a_{n+1}-a_n\,\big|<\epsilon\ $ for all $\ n\ge N\ $.

With this as the induction base, the statement you 'd be trying to prove  (and can, in fact, prove) by induction for all positive integers $ \ k\ $ is

> For any $\ \epsilon>0\ $ there is a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that $\ \big|\,a_{n+k}-a_n\,\big|<\epsilon\ $ for all $\ n\ge N\ $.

*But this being true for all $\ k>0\ $ is not the Cauchy criterion for convergence*; it is merely a statement that $\ \,a_{n+k}-a_n\rightarrow0\ $ for all positive integers $\ k\ $.

I suspect you're confusing the above-quoted statement with the following version of Cauchy's criterion

> For any $\ \epsilon>0\ $ there is a positive integer $\ N\ $ such that $\ \big|\,a_{n+k}-a_n\,\big|<\epsilon\ $ for all $\ n\ge N\ $ and all positive integers $\ k\ $.

It might help you see the difference between these statements by expressing them with symbolic quantifiers.  The first is
$$
\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\,\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge N\,\big|\,a_{n+k}-a_n\,\big|<\epsilon\ ,
$$
whereas the version of Cauchy's criterion given above is
$$
\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge N\,\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\ \big|\,a_{n+k}-a_n\,\big|<\epsilon\ .
$$
In the first of these statements the existential quantifier over $\ N\ $ appears *after* the universal quantifier over $\ k\ $ which means that $\ N\ $ can, and generally will, depend on the value of $\ k\ $. In the Cauchy criterion, however, the existential quantifier over $\ N\ $ appears *before* the universal quantifier over $\ k\ $, which makes it impossible for $\ N\ $ to depend on $\ k\ $.